# samba file sharing gives 0x80070043 in windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, samba, file-server

I have samba set up on ubuntu server, and trying to share folders inside `sharedfolders` at the root directory. However, I get this error `0x80070043` in windows.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -lh sharedfolders/
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K May 26 16:10 f1
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K May 26 16:10 f2
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4.0K May 26 16:11 f3
```

and here is my samba config file:

```
[global]
workgroup = KIWI
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
wins support = yes
dns proxy = no
name resolve order = lmhosts host wins bcast
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
security = user
server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user   
usershare allow guests = yes
[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
    guest ok = no
    read only = yes
    create mask = 0700
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
    browseable = yes
    read only = yes
    guest ok = no
[Shared]
    comment = Shared Files
    path = sharedfolders/f1
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
[Home Files]
    comment = Home Files
    path = sharedfolders/f2
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
[Work Files]
    comment = Work Files
    path = sharedfolders/f3
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
```

when I try to connect to one of the above folders (f1,f2,f3), I provide the user pass defined in samba, but I get this strange error.

Could somebody help me solve this problem?

and here is my samba status:

```
root@ubuntu:~# smbstatus

Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
PID     Username      Group         Machine            Protocol Version
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------

No locked files
```

### update:

here is the permissions for the root folder where my three shared folders are:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -lh
total 4.0K
drwxrwxrwx 5 root root 4.0K May 26 16:11 sharedfolders
```

### Image annex:

windows:
[image]

ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: A ten second web search reveals that the error is 0x80070043 [The Network Name Cannot Be Found](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fb8adefa-7128-46f7-a67e-b36feed2d31a/0x80070043-the-network-name-cannot-be-found?forum=winserverfiles).

Comment: @JohanMyréen yeah i know it is the error, but what is the solution? please help thanks

Comment: It means your problem is related to DNS instead of Samba. Try connecting via IP address.

Comment: @MichaelMol i did, i put `\\192.168.0.200\Home Files` and still nothing.

Comment: "still nothing" is not an error message.

Comment: @MichaelMol it is the same, i get the `0x80070043` and it says that the network Name not found.

Comment: That's going to be a problem on your Windows host, not the Samba server.

Comment: @MichaelMol i have the same problem in my virtual ubuntu running on vmware windows.

Comment: You get 0x80070043 accessing a Samba share from a _Linux_ host?

Comment: @MichaelMol i thought it goes without saying that it has similar problem here is the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/OZhDyij.png

Comment: That's a different error. 0x80070043 refers to not being able to find the host by the host's name. You need to be much more specific about the errors you're describing; not all failures are equal.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem to address is that none of the share paths in your Samba configuration file is properly defined.

For example, here:

> ```
> [Shared]
>     path = sharedfolders/f1
> ```

You need to provide an absolute path (ie one starting with `/`), not a relative one.

You'll see reasons for error messages in the Samba log files. You've defined them, so make use of them.

Answer (score -1):

you have some permission problems at the folder you are sharing:

solution is that you move it to the `/mnt/sharedfolders/`

```
mv sharedfolders/ /mnt/
```

and then :

```
 chown -R www-data sharedfolders
```

and then update the paths in the samba config file accordingly,

and then of course:

```
service smbd restart
```

hope this works.